# How to sort record inside views in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem with regards in sorting inside the View on SQL Server 2008. 
Please refer to the Image below.

[image]

as you can see in the designer, i've sort the Column SeqID (Int Datatype), but when i select the View, the the Sorted Column seems not working.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to sort a view? A view is like a table so you sort it when you select from it:

```
select * from V_APDoc order by SeqID DESC;
```

Comment: Yes i know that workaround but my requirements not suit with your suggestions. I'm calling several views in only 1 form that's why i cannot "HARD CODE" the ORDER BY Clause.

Comment: i cannot accept your answer since it doesn't satisfy my question since i'm talking about sorting inside the views not in the query.

Comment: No problem. You do not have to accept my answer. I just shared what I knew. As posted by @astander below, the documentation clearly states that you are trying to do something that is not supported. Good luck.

Comment: its kind of weird that Microsoft add a sorting options in the View designer. it doesn't make sense, thanks by the way, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

> The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are
>   returned by the TOP or OFFSET clause in the view definition. The ORDER
>   BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when the view is queried,
>   unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself.

From the quote, you should always specifiy the SORT ORDER if you wish to guarantee the ordered results.